# How do I choose a particular DbSet from a DbContext using EFCore 3.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My app works with 5 tables right now, maybe more in the future, and I would like to minimize code duplication. One example below is for Swd0004 and I also have the same code for Swd0013, and other duplicated functions for each table. The user chooses what table to work with from a drop down box. I'd like to take this drop down box selection and somehow pass that to the functions.

```
private void SWD_0004_Lookup()
{
    using (var ctx = new EFContext())
    {
        var query = ctx.Swd0004;
        var readList = query.ToList();
        Debug.WriteLine("QUERY COUNT: " + readList.Count);
        // create datatable from query results so I can populate datagridview
        var dt = LINQResultToDataTable(query);
        dgvQueryResults.DataSource = dt;
        GetColumnHeaders(dt);
        DataDT = dt; // copy local dt so we can use DataDT for getting record data
    }
}
```

This is a database first app. Swd0004 is a table in a database and therefore a DbSet in my EFContext class.
My `Swd0004` class:

```cs
namespace SWDDB.Models
{
    public partial class Swd0004
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
...
```

Then do I need to add a generic to it to implement @abdusco answer? Maybe I'm not familiar enough with generics.

```cs
    public partial class Swd0004<TEntity> : ??? where TEntity : class
```

Here's another example:

```cs
private List<Swd0004> ConvertDT(DataTable dt)
{
    var importList = new List<Swd0004>();
    // convert DataRow object to SWD object, otherwise BulkInsert will fail
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var obj = CreateItemFromRow<Swd0004>(row);
        // BulkInsert needs a list
        importList.Add(obj);
    }
    return importList;
}
```

As you can see, I have to explicitly state Swd0004 three times. So I would have to duplicate this function for each table, 5 times.

`UPDATE`
I'm trying to implement what @bolkay suggested. I created this class:

```cs
using SWDDB.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace SWDDB
{
    public abstract class BaseLookup<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        public virtual void PerformLookup()
        {
            using (var ctx = new EFContext())
            {
                var query = ctx.Set<TEntity>();
                Debug.WriteLine("QUERY COUNT: " + query.ToList().Count);
            }
        }
    }
    public class SWD0004Lookup : BaseLookup<Swd0004>
    {
        
    }
}
```

It feels like I'm close but I can't figure out how to call PerformLookup from my mainline code.

Comment: Why would you want to do that when the context already has `DbSet` properties? What are you trying to do? Instead of reducing code duplication (there's no duplicate in `ctx.Customers.Where(...)`) you *increase* it

Comment: In fact, what's the point of all this code? It loads the entire table with `ctx.Sqd004.ToList()` (which is a rather weird *entity* name) and then does ... what? All .NET stacks, all controls bind to collections, not just data tables. Even Windows Forms.

Comment: This part of the app is so a user can verify the table contents after an upload of a revised document. The table is small, that's why I'm pulling the entire thing. There is a bunch more code that I didn't show.

Comment: Again, why are you using a DataTable at all? That's what you try to avoid using, and isn't even needed because all controls bind to collections. Even if you really need a datatable, you can use one of the Extension methods that produce a DataTable from any IEnumerable, eg MoreLINQ's [ToDataTable](https://morelinq.github.io/3.0/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_ToDataTable__2_1.htm). MoreLINQ is available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq). You can also copy and use individual operators too

Comment: All this code can be replaced with `dgvQueryResults.DataSource = ctx.Swd0004.ToDataTable()`. Although `dgvQueryResults.DataSource =ctx.Swd0004.ToList()` is valid too, because controls can bind to collections.

Comment: My LINQResultToDataTable extension is the ToDataTable extension as shown here. https://www.extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/todatatable I need a datatable because later I transpose the selected record vertically to a couple of list boxes.

Comment: That doesn't mean you need to "select" a DbSet. You could pass the DbSet or far better, the IQueryable as a parameter. There's no need to hard-code the DbContext or the DbSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the logic behind users selecting a table to work with.

You can do something like this as a starting point to remove duplication of methods.

Create a base class with the logic.

```
    public abstract class BaseLookUp<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        public virtual void PerformLookup()
        {
            using (var ctx = new EFContext())
            {
                var query = ctx.Set<TEntity>();
                //etc...
            }
        }
    }
    public class SWD004Lookup : BaseLookUp<SWD004004>
    {

    }
```

Totally depending on your needs, you could just make it a static method etc.

Comment: @EE_Kraig Are you familiar with Generics? This is just a suggested approach.

Comment: well, `TEntity` must be an entity class type. What is `Swd004`?

Comment: The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()
@abdusco Thoughts?

Comment: The line `var query = ctx.Set<TEntity>();` is still throwing the above error. @abdusco

Comment: @bolkay Could you check my updated question and maybe help with my last mile!

Comment: Join me in the [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225842/chat-with-ee-kraig).

Comment: OK I got it. Don't know why it took me so long to work this out.

var temp = new SWD0004Lookup();

Answer (score 0):

[You can get a `DbSet` using `DbContext.Set<TEntity>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Set__1_System_String_) instead of using properties in your `EfContext` class:

```cs
private void SWD_Lookup<TEntity>() // <-- turn it into a generic method
{
    using (var ctx = new EFContext())
    {
        var query = ctx.Set<TEntity>(); // <-- get dbset by passing the type
        // ...
    }
}
```

then you can call it like this:

```cs
SWD_Lookup<Swd0004>();
SWD_Lookup<Swd0013>();
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `Set<>`. The context already has `DbSet<>` properties with the configured *entities*. `Set<>` itself won't work unless the entities are already configured. This is a more verbose way of writing `ctx.Swd0004`

Comment: True, but according to his code, there are already `DbSet` properties defined in his `EfContext` class. Using the `DbContext.Set<T>` method allows him to reuse the same logic, which is exactly what he wants

Comment: It doesn't. What *would* would be an extension method on `DbSet<>`. Even so, what this code does isn't meaningful. All controls can bind on collections, there's no reason to convert to DataTable. And even then, there are `ToDataTable()` or `AsDatatable()` extension methods that return DataTables. That's the only logic that gets repeated here

Comment: I agree, but, there's not much to discuss with 8 lines of code he's posted. We're facing with an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem?oldformat=true) here